# Send Parameter via POST Instead of GET in remote rule of JQuery Validation Library directly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to learn `JQuery`, and was trying to understand the various rules in the `validate` library(https://jqueryvalidation.org/).
However, I noticed that even if my HTML `<form id="myform">` has `method="POST"`, the remote request to my check-email.php is sent via GET and not POST. Here is the `validate` rule I'm using:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "check-email.php"
        }
    }
});
```

I am wondering how I can send the request to `check-email.php` via `POST` instead of `GET` without using any explicit AJAX.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: without ajax? then you'll be forcing a full reload of the page everytime a validation request is sent, and your users will abandon your site in droves because of a horribly crappy experience.

Comment: I meant without an explicit AJAX request, remote has an implicit one i believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering how I can send the request to `check-email.php` via `POST` instead of `GET` without any explicit AJAX.

That doesn't even make sense.  Since the `remote` method is facilitated via `ajax()`, using `remote` without Ajax is entirely impossible.

> the remote request to my `check-email.php` is sent via `GET` and not `POST`

[Following the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), you can use any jQuery `.ajax()` setting.

So simply set the `type` to `POST`...

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "check-email.php",
                type: 'POST'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to make sure that ALL validate requests are sent via POST by default, overriding GET?

Comment: @AyushGupta, this is CLIENT-SIDE validation, so **none** of the validation requests are sent anywhere, **except** for `remote`... hence the name "remote".

Comment: I understand that. What I mean is, that say I have 5 fields which need to use remote, is there any way i can make sure that if I dont write `type: 'POST'` all 5 fields are sent via POST, overriding GET. 

Also, by without AJAX, i meant wthout any explicit AJAX, not the implicit one

Comment: @AyushGupta, I have no idea why you're asking about "explicit" Ajax, when the **only** Ajax we're talking about is whatever is already built into `remote`.  And yes, you'll have to set `type` every time you declare `remote`.